# Как передать результат выполнения PHP метода на конкретный адрес

Tags: php, api, curl, php-curl

Первый раз реализую API и провожу интеграцию с другим сервисом.

Суть такая:

1) Мой метод принимает JSON документ в котором есть такое поле как callback_url

2) Обрабатываю данные и генерирую ответ в JSON

3) Отправляю ответ на callback_url

На текущий момент данные я получаю, обрабатываю, формирую запрос и по cURL отправляю на callback_url, но он туда не доходит.

Подскажите, куда мне копать.

Код отправки ответа:

```
public function sendStatus($url, $status, $code){
        // http_response_code($code);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $status);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $response;
```

лог отправки такой

```
*   Trying 217.172.26.37...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test.url (217.172.26.37) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/test.php HTTP/1.1
Host: test.url
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 47

* upload completely sent off: 47 out of 47 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx-reuseport/1.13.4
< Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2020 11:23:46 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 176
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=30
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.40
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< 
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host test.url left intact
```

Comment: Как ты понял, что он не доходит и что записывается в response?

Comment: интегрируюсь со сторонним сервисом и callback_url приходит от них. При тестировании выяснили, что к ним ответа не приходит.

Comment: Выведи лог `$curl_log = fopen("curl_log.txt", 'w+');
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_STDERR, $curl_log);
curl_setopt($curl_desc, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);`

Comment: лог добавил в тело вопроса

Comment: `$response` то запишите куда то в лог. курл вам ответ 200 дал, значит запрос отправлен и принят. 276 байт в ответ ушло, вот и смотрите что в них. мб описание ошибки.

Comment: Даа, вы правы, там код ошибки. Спасибо